# async eachseries how pass var after finish loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass **var** **number** to callback, after loop.
For example Invenotry array has 25 items.
So after this 25 steps I want to pass number into callback (inCb), because I need to check number value.

```
    var number = 0;
    async.eachSeries(inventory, function(item, inCb) {
    if(sth == othersthm)
    {
      number++;

    }
    }, function(numb) {
     check number value and do sth

     });
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please provide more detail as to what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: please explain your requirement bit more clearly

Comment: Sorry, please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use number:

```
var number = 0;
async.eachSeries(inventory, function(item, inCb) {
    if (sth == othersthm) {
        number++;
    }
}, function() {
    //check number value and do sth
    console.log(number);
});
```